# Zappa: Issue while running lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa, python-zappa

I have a sample flask application and recently with the help of `zappa` i tryed deploying exiting flask application on lambda.

Basically, I performed these stuff

```
pip install zappa
provided zappa_settings.json file as a input
zappa package dev -o myproject.zip
```

zappa_setting.json file

```
{
    "dev": {
        "slim_handler": true,
        "app_function": "myproject.main.app",
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "project_name": "myproject",
        "runtime": "python3.8",
        "s3_bucket": "mybucket-dev"
    },
    "stage": {
        "slim_handler": true,
        "app_function": "myproject.main.app",
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "project_name": "myproject",
        "runtime": "python3.8",
        "s3_bucket": "mybucket-stage"
    },
    "master": {
        "slim_handler": true,
        "app_function": "myproject.main.app",
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "project_name": "myproject",
        "runtime": "python3.8",
        "s3_bucket": "mybucket"
    }
}
```

when i run the `zappa package dev -o myproject.zip`, it is creating a `myproject.zip` file and i placed that zip file in s3 bucket `mybucket-dev`. then i provided this zip file as an input to lambda.

**when i try to run lambda function i am experiencing an issue**

**Error**

```
botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
```

i gone through the logs and found that,

```
Calling s3:get_object with {'Bucket': 'mybucket-dev', 'Key': 'dev_mybucket_current_project.tar.gz'}
```

my zip file name is `mybucket.zip` and logs are showing this `dev_mybucket_current_project.tar.gz`.

from where this compressed file is coming?

**can anyone suggest a solution for this?**

Comment: I think this is a file [created](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1085) as part of zappa deployment. Did you check your bucket if its there?

Comment: i checked in the bucket, it is not there in s3